# How do I fix the "javascript from another domain which is blocked or failed to load" error?

Tags: support

I keep getting a strange message when I load scicomp.stackexchange.com from my windows explorer and google chrome browsers:

"Computational Science requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load"

This problem also seems to prevent me from viewing other features of the website, including tag suggestions when submitting a question (such as the current question).

Has anyone else had this problem?

How do I fix it?

Comment: I've pushed this to the SE employees...

Answer (score 3):

This message means that http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js was unable to be loaded.

This could be from a number of things:  antivirus settings, a proxy, browser settings.

You can find some troubleshooting tips [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load).